# Spatial weights: asymmetric adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, gis, spatial, adjacency-matrix

I am creating an adjacency matrix to do spatial analysis in R. The data are all counties in the continental US. I've got the counties spatial polygons from US Census Tiger files.

I am able to create the neighbors list, and it is symmetric. But when I convert that to an adjacency matrix it is not symmetric. This is a problem because my goal is to run a spatial autologistic model using `ngspatial::autologistic`, and I get an error that I must supply a symmetric binary adjacency matrix.

Here is my R code to create the adjacency matrix:

```
us<-readShapeSpatial("County_2010Census_DP1.shp")
#Trim out counties outside of continental US
us2<-us[!substr(us$GEOID10,1,2)%in%c('02','60','66','78','15','72'),]
us2.nb = poly2nb(us2)
is.symmetric.nb(us2.nb) #Comes out true
us2.adj = nb2mat(us2.nb, style="B",zero.policy=F)
isSymmetric(us2.adj) #comes out false
```

As an aside, I am able to use `splogit` with this adjacency matrix without a problem. I'm no expert on spatial analysis, so I can't say I know what is going on within these commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix `us2.adj` is symmetric. The problem is with the test. It turns out that

```
isSymmetric(us2.adj)
```

uses `all.equal(...)` to test for equality of the matrix with it's transpose, and `all.equal(...)` checks the attributes as well as the values. `nb2mat(...)` creates a matrix with the row names set to the polygon IDs and the column names unset. So `all.equal(...)` returns `FALSE` and therefore so does `isSymmetric(...)`. Evidently, the `autologistic(...)` function uses this same test.

```
us2.adj <- nb2mat(us2.nb, style="B",zero.policy=F)
isSymmetric(us2.adj)
# [1] FALSE
isSymmetric(us2.adj,check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

The simple solution is to either set the columns names to the row names, or set the row names to `NULL`.

```
x <- us2.adj
colnames(x) <- rownames(x)
isSymmetric(x)
# [1] TRUE
y <- us2.adj
rownames(y) <- NULL
isSymmetric(y)
# [1] TRUE
```

BTW, I think the reason this question went unanswered for 18 hours is that you did not provide a link to your shapefile. If you do not provide a reproducible example, the tendency is for members to ignore or downvote the question. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for instructions

Comment: Thanks! I can't upvote you yet, but this is just what I needed. I wasn't aware of how to share the shapefile, and it is quite large, so thanks for the advice there.

Comment: Well, you must have downloaded it from somewhere? Just put that link in your question. I found it here: http://isismapping.org/springfield/GIS_data/County_2010Census_DP1.zip.